# How to traverse element relationship in EA using SQL and VBScript

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

Enterprise Architect (EA): I'm trying to use VBScript to traverse the relationships of an element. I've narrowed down to do custom SQL. I have done select * from T_* on all the tables in EA and cannot find out where the relationship links are stored.

Answer (score 1):

`t_connector.start_object_id` to `t_connector.end_object_id` mark the two `t_object.object_id` elements the connector relates.

Comment: My Inside EA book http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html might give you a few more insights.

Answer (score 1):

In order to traverse the relations of an element you should not use custom SQL, but simply iterate the `EA.Element.Connectors` collection

Something like

```
option explicit

!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript

sub main
    dim package as EA.Package
    set package = Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage
    dim element as EA.Element
    for each element in package.Elements
        dim connector as EA.Connector
        for each connector in element.Connectors
            Session.Output "connector type: " & connector.Type & " connector name: " & connector.Name
        next
    next
end sub

main
```

Comment: Thanx. I would rather iterate than query where I can. I select a package that had requirements then ran the script. It did not provide a connection name. Also, is it possible to get the element object on the end of the connection.

Comment: I need to "walk" my requirements and determine if they have been mapped to a Business Activity.

Comment: Lew, if you check the connector documentation you will see that it contains the Object_ID's of the start and end object. You can use those ID in `Repository.GetElementByID()` to get a hold of the EA.Element at either side.